# PHP: Is there a way to get the return type of a method?

Tags: php, reflection, php-5.6

Given the following code structure is there a way that I can get the return type of FooFactory->createService method with PHP 5.6? I've tried ReflectionClass and ReflectionMethod classes but couldn't find a way.Thanks in advance.

```
class FooFactory implements FactoryInterface {
    public function createService(/*args*/)
    {
        $foo = new Foo();
        // ...
        //inject dependencies
        // ...
        return $foo;
    }
}

class Foo {
    /*...methods...*/
}
```

Edit: I need to get the class name without creating an instance of the FooFactory.

Comment: Not with PHP 5, you'd have to analyse the actual code in the method.... PHP7 introduces return typehinting, but it is only optional

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP5 this is not possible.

You could (and this is more of a workaround than a solution) type hint your variable on declaration. This would expose the methods etc belonging to created service to your IDE.

Example:

```
/* @var \MyFooService $myFooService */
$myFooService = FooFactory->createServixce('MyFooService');
```

Note it is the @var declaration that will inform your editor of the variable type.

Syntax being:

```
/* @var [CLASS_NAME] [VARIABLE] */
```

UPDATE:

Just seen you dont want to create an instance of FooFactory.
By default arn't factory methods static?

So:

```
$fooFactory = new FooFactory();
$fooService = FooFactory->getService('FooService');
```

Becomes:

```
$fooService = FooFactory::getService('FooService');
```